# Rollover Image change a larger images z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index, rollover

I am trying to set a rollover image to rollover a larger, main image.

Effectively one thumbnail rollover affects a larger rollover image; I have managed to do this successfully when assigning the rollover to my navbar, except it does not work when i assign it to the thumbnail rollover within this navbar.

so; this code works;

```
 #navbar:hover ~ #smile {
    z-index: 10;
    }
```

but I want to change the z-index when the hover is over .leftelement class, not navbar

```
 .leftelement:hover ~ #smile {
    z-index: 10;
    }
```

^^^ why does this not work?!^^^

here is a fiddle; any help would be so much appreciated, or a push in the right direction;

http://jsfiddle.net/YJ7yb/1/

thank you!

Comment: It doesn't work because `~` is a sibling combinator, and `#smile` is not a sibling of `.leftelement`, whereas it is a sibling of `#navbar`.

Comment: thank you for your reply, do you have any pointers where I can read up on sibling combinators?

Comment: There's a fantastic article about CSS selectors here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: Do you have a recomendation of an alternative selector I could use in the place of    ~ that is more generic?

Comment: There isn't a selector that will allow you to traverse back up the tree, for example a parent.  You'd need to do that in order to find the parent's sibling.  Of course you could do this with JavaScript and add a class on hover, or you could restructure your HTML.

Comment: Hey! thank you very much; you have cleared this up for a pleb like me. spent too much time trying to work this out! thanks again